# Project syncing error, while connecting firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

Please Help

When I connect my project file with fireBase the following error comes up.

```
null    
resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info (aka com.kangkan.developer.f_c_m:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info) not found.   
resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification (aka com.kangkan.developer.f_c_m:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification) not found. 
resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time (aka com.kangkan.developer.f_c_m:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time) not found.   
resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title (aka com.kangkan.developer.f_c_m:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title) not found. 
failed linking references.
```

[The Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhrAk.png)

**R** class also showed error

I've cleaned the project, invalidate caches/restart,

It's not gone, I am using the firebase core `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'`

Answer (score 0):

This can result in several reasons.

1. Make sure you are using an updated version of `android-gradle-plugin`
2. Make sure there are no dependency version clashed in `build.gradle` file.
3. Check whether your XML resources don't have errors.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help. but, I Checked all those things, It does not work.